# fs.writeFile is not returning pdf file as it's content is

Tags: jquery, node.js, mime-types, content-type, fs

I'm getting some file from some link(basically anchor href) using ajax then I'm sending the content to node server as follows:

```
<a class="myTag" href="/getFiledata?uid=7674&&pass=75876789">Download</a>
```

.

```
jQuery.get(jQuery("a.myTag").attr("href"), function(data, status){
            console.log("typeof data: ",typeof data);
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : 'https://7c099919.ngrok.io/fildta?fileTyp=naukriDta',
                type : 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data : JSON.stringify({bdy:data}),
                arrayKey:'',
                processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            console.log("Data: ",data );
        });
```

I'm listning and writing data on server as follows:

```
function(req, res, next){
                var fd=path.join(__dirname,"../upld/tmp.pdf");
                console.log("req body:  ",JSON.stringify(req.body));
                fs.writeFile(fd, req.body.bdy, function(err) {
                    if (err){
                        console.log(fd,"\n\n\n\n\n Can not write to above file:\n\n",err);
                    }else {
                        console.log(fd,' is Done');
                    }
                });
                console.log("req query:  ",req.query);
                res.send({"msg":"File is uploaded"});
            }
```

but when I do read created pdf file using any reader it shows blank but when I read its content using notepad++ the content is same as It was on client.

the content of file is as follows:

````
Data: %PDF-1.5
%����
24 0 obj
<<
/Linearized 1
/L 121184
/H [ 1971 370 ]
/O 26
/E 98912
/N 4
/T 120577
>>
endobj

xref
24 70
0000000017 00000 n
0000001869 00000 n
0000002341 00000 n
0000002744 00000 n
0000002924 00000 n
0000003187 00000 n
0000003532 00000 n
0000003720 00000 n
0000003999 00000 n
0000008165 00000 n
0000008222 00000 n
0000008397 00000 n
0000008655 00000 n
0000008884 00000 n
0000009034 00000 n
0000009064 00000 n
0000009246 00000 n
0000009328 00000 n
0000009601 00000 n
0000018049 00000 n
0000018198 00000 n
0000018570 00000 n
0000018753 00000 n
0000019026 00000 n
0000025387 00000 n
0000025414 00000 n
0000025569 00000 n
0000025599 00000 n
0000025786 00000 n
0000026064 00000 n
0000036489 00000 n
0000036867 00000 n
0000037320 00000 n
0000037509 00000 n
0000037787 00000 n
0000045277 00000 n
0000045492 00000 n
0000045642 00000 n
0000045672 00000 n
0000045854 00000 n
0000046128 00000 n
0000061832 00000 n
0000062215 00000 n
0000062645 00000 n
0000062828 00000 n
0000063102 00000 n
0000069388 00000 n
0000069443 00000 n
0000069592 00000 n
0000069622 00000 n
0000069803 00000 n
0000070073 00000 n
0000073366 00000 n
0000073411 00000 n
0000073718 00000 n
0000073873 00000 n
0000073903 00000 n
0000074090 00000 n
0000074369 00000 n
0000083843 00000 n
0000084123 00000 n
0000084551 00000 n
0000084699 00000 n
0000084729 00000 n
0000084909 00000 n
0000085193 00000 n
0000093386 00000 n
0000093570 00000 n
0000093941 00000 n
0000001971 00000 n
trailer
<<
/Size 94
/Prev 120566
/Info 23 0 R
/Root 25 0 R
/ID [<4e891be7c450bedc9528eba318fe1823><4e891be7c450bedc9528eba318fe1823>]
>>
startxref
0
%%EOF

25 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 22 0 R
/Lang (en-IN)
/MarkInfo << /Marked true >>
>>
endobj
93 0 obj
<<
/S 188
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 280
>>
stream
x�c```b``������*� Ȁ
````

I'm naive in MIME-TYPE and file content concept. I think somewhere I'm missing to set certain data(MIME-TYPE,content-type etc) before writing the file.

> Basically My aim is to redirect the file got from anchor to my node server.

Comment: Wouldn't it make way more sense to send the URL to the server and let the server download the file, instead downloading and re-uploading it?

Comment: The page is using some cookies, referer etc before sending file so it blocks if the request goes from server

Comment: Try to use [XMLHttpRequest2](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) to download the file as a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) (most browsers [support xhr2](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) nowadays). When you have a blob you can upload that easily and without getting into any character encoding trouble.

Comment: Yea it worked. Thanks.

Comment: If you share the code in an answer of your own, I'll upvote it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Tomalak suggested to use xhr2. I just added responseType/dataType to blob/binary depending upon javascript/jQuery it worked.

the client code is as follows:
- First method:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('GET', jQuery("a.myTag").attr("href"), true);
   xhr.responseType = 'blob';

   xhr.onload = function(e) {
       if (this.status == 200) {
           // get binary data as a response
           var blob = this.response;
           var base64data;
           var reader = new window.FileReader();
           reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
           reader.onloadend = function() {
               base64data = reader.result;
               var myDta={bdy:base64data};
               console.log("myDta",myDta);
               jQuery.ajax({
                   url : 'https://7c099919.ngrok.io/fildta?fileTyp=naukriDta',
                   type : 'POST',
                   data : myDta,
                   success : function(data) {
                       console.log(data);
                   }
               });
           };
       }
   };

   xhr.send();
```

Second method

```
$.ajax({
  url: jQuery("a.myTag").attr("href"),
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "binary",
  processData: false,
  success: function(result){
      // same stuffs with binary data as above
  }
});
```

The server code is as follows:

```
function(req, res, next){
                var fd=path.join(__dirname,"../upld/tmp.pdf");
                console.log("req body:  ",JSON.stringify(req.body));
                var base64Data = req.body.bdy.replace(/^data:application\/pdf;base64,/, "");
                console.log("base64Data  ",base64Data);
                fs.writeFile(fd, base64Data,'base64', function(err) {
                    if (err){
                        console.log(fd,"\n\n\n\n\n Can not write to above file:\n\n",err);
                    }else {
                        console.log(fd,' is Done');
                    }
                });
                console.log("req query:  ",req.query);
                res.send({"msg":"File is uploaded"});
            }
```

Wohoo.. It worked :)

> Strictly speaking XHR2 isn't HTML5. However, it's part of the
>   incremental improvements browser vendors are making to the core
>   platform.